# How to copy strings from different text files to show side by side, in separate columns, into a third file in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, awk

Currently I have two txt files that have 200 lines of strings each. The second file is an updated version of the first, so I want to combine them in Bash into a third file, where each line shows first the original file's string, and then the updated file's string in a separate column. So it would be 200 lines of strings, with each line showing the original and updated versions in separate columns side by side. Is this possible?

Comment: What you also might be interested in are tools like `tkdiff` or `meld` or any other diff tool.

Answer (score 2):

Use paste like this

```
paste file1 file2
```

From `man paste`

> Write lines consisting of the sequentially corresponding lines from each FILE, separated by TABs, to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spreadsheets. 
It did the trick for me.